# Target only some footnotes with para footmisc

Tags: footnotes

I have four small footnotes. I want the first two to appear in separate lines, and the last ones to appear together in the same line. When I try `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`, they all appear in a single line.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{FN1.\\}
Some text.\footnote{FN2.\\}
Some text.\footnote{FN3.}
Some text.\footnote{FN4.}
\end{document}
```

This shows (note the spaces before `2` and `3`):

```
1 FT1.
  2 FT2.
  3 FT3.   4 FT4.
```

What I need instead:

```
1 FT1.
2 FT2.
3 FT3.    4 FT4.
```

Comment: Will you consider adding a full MWE?

Comment: @pushpen.paul updated.

Answer (score 1):

Does that work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Some text.\footnotemark[1]
Some text.\footnotemark[2]
Some text.\footnotemark[3]
Some text.\footnotemark[4]

\footnotetext[1]{FN1.\\}

\footnotetext[2]{FN2.\\}

\footnotetext[3]{FN3.} \footnotetext[4]{FN4.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want footnotes 3 and 4 to appear in the same line.

Comment: OOPS. Sorry, I forgot what your real problem was! :-( Starting afresh...

Comment: Notes 3 and 4 now appear on the same line, but that line and note 2 are indented, while note 1 is not.  Adding the `flushmargin` or `marginal` options of `footmisc` doesn’t fix the problem, unfortunately.